# Python - how to access values assigned to variables in one function from a different function that returns multiple variable values

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables, global

New to Python and trying to move away from using the `global` keyword as part of passing variable values between functions.

I understand that `return` returns a tuple - but I'd like to be able to reference the variable I'm calling by name rather than by indexing and at this stage of my learning I'd like to avoid classes.

Is the simplified code example below a viable way of doing this or is there a more standard or 'pythonic' method? Seems like this requires including all the variables the called function returns?

So far - this is the only other method I've found for passing multiple variable values between functions that doesn't involve indexes or classes.

```
def myfunct_01():
    
    my_var_01 = 1
    my_var_02 = "stuff"
    my_var_03 = (10 , 9 , 8)
    
    return my_var_01, my_var_02, my_var_03

myfunct_01()

def myfunct_02():
    
    my_var_01, my_var_02, my_var_03 = myfunct_01()
    
    my_var_04 = my_var_01 + 1
    my_var_05 = my_var_03[0] - my_var_03[1]

    return my_var_04, my_var_05

myfunct_02()
```

Comment: What's your question?  When you do `my_var_01, my_var_02, my_var_03 = ...` you probably want to use better variable names.  What are the three things being returned by `my_funct_01`.  You could also replace `my_var_02` with `_`, which is the Python standard way of saying "I'm ignoring this value".

Comment: Technically, you don't pass anything betwen functions, because your functions don't have parameters and thus don't take any arguments when calling them. The call `myfunct_01()` on separate file before definition of `myfunct_02` is redundant.

Comment: You could have your functions return dictionaries rather than tuples if you want to access results by named key. However, returning a tuple and unpacking it inline with something like `my_var_01, my_var_02, my_var_03 = myfunct_01()` is pretty pythonic. As has been said, if you used more meaningful variable names, this would likely "click" better in your mental model.

Comment: Also you should understand the concept of scope. `my_var_01`, `my_var_02`, `my_var_03` defined in `myfunct_02` are local to that function. Also, the last line `myfunct_02()` will call the function, but you just throw away the values returned

Comment: FYI - since this has been called out multiple times - I went with these variable names to try and keep my code example simple and clear. Definitely would not do this IRL.

Comment: @slothrop "However, returning a tuple and unpacking it inline with something like my_var_01, my_var_02, my_var_03 = myfunct_01() is pretty pythonic." That's what I was after. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, yes, you get used to seeing things like `income, expenses, profit = calc_financial_data()` and it feels pretty natural when the names are meaningful.

Comment: You mean something like `my_var_01, my_var_02, (a, b, c) = myfunct_01()`?

Comment: @FrankYellin My question: Is the (purposely very basic) code example I posted a viable way of allowing `myfunct_02()` to access the values assigned to variables in `myfunct_01()`?

Comment: You're not accessing the *variables*; you are accessing the return values. The variables used inside `myfunct1_01` aren't relevant to anyone *outside* that function. This is *exactly* how functions are supposed to work: you pass values as arguments (so that the function does not depend on any particular variables outside the function) and the function returns values (so no one outside the function needs to worry about function-local variables).

Comment: @chepner Yes - I'm aware of that and I did try and refer specifically to 'variable values' in the body of the question. I've updated the title to try and make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python dictionary to refer variables to their names by having them as keys.

```py
def myfunct_01():
    d1 = {}
    d1['my_var_01'] = 1
    d1['my_var_02'] = "stuff"
    d1['my_var_03'] = (10 , 9 , 8)
    
    return d1

myfunct_01()

def myfunct_02():
    
    d1 = myfunct_01()
    my_var_01 = d1['my_var_01']
    my_var_02 = d1['my_var_02']
    my_var_03 = d1['my_var_03']
    
    d2 = {}
    d2['my_var_04'] = my_var_01 + 1
    d2['my_var_05'] = my_var_03[0] - my_var_03[1]

    return d2

myfunct_02()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignments, it's quite straightforward:

```
first, second = (1,2)
print(fist, second)
# 1 2
```

So in your example you could call the function like this:

```
my_var_01, my_var_02, my_var_03 = myfunct_01()
```

You can as well unpack part of the items in a list.

```
first, *rest = (1,2,3,4)
print(first, rest)
# 1 [2,3,4]
```